200% growth is trebled or quadrupled in size?
Percentage growth is counter-intuitive. So 100% growth means something has doubled in size. But what does 200% growth mean? Has it trebled or quadrupled in size? What then does 150% growth mean. What does 250% growth mean?

"Percent growth" is an ambiguous phrase, but if "100% growth" means doubling, then "200% growth" should mean tripling.

One of the confusing things about percentage growth is that growing by $x%$ twice is not the same as growing by $2x%$ once. Also, an $x%$ increase followed by an $x%$ decrease doesn't bring you back to the original amount.

But the formula for $x%$ growth, applied one time only, is very simple. It's $(\text{new amount}) = (\text{old amount}) + \frac x{100}\times(\text{old amount}).$ This can also be written $(\text{new amount}) = (\text{old amount}) \times (1 + \frac x{100})$. Just plug your numbers into these formulas.

For example, $100%$ growth means doubling because $1 + \frac{100}{100} = 2$.

It is common to define the factor we have to multiply with a given size to increase this size by $p$%. The factor is $1+\frac{p}{100}$ , hence $200$% gives factor $3$ (tripling) and you can easily determine the other factors.
